# Can HTTP-header LAST-UPDATED be trusted?

Tags: http

I have been using [Rex Swain's HTTP Viewer](http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html) to verify that none of the texts on a certain webpage has been changed recently.

The response was: "Code last updated 21 January 2012", so as I understand it, I can't really assume that anything was actually changed on that date but is it safe to assume that none of the texts on the webpage has been changed since that date?

I am not an HTTP expert, so please use layman terms where possible, thanks :-)

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web server typically uses the corresponding file's *last updated* attribute as the value for the HTTP `Last-Modified` header, so in **general** it can be trusted, but it's always possible that the date is wrong, for whatever reason.

The `Last-Modified` header is usually used for caches, to populate the `If-Modified-Since` header in subsequent requests.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, Mark!